# Sencha touch upgrade from 2.0 to 2.3 - List not visible

Tags: list, extjs, touch, height, upgrade

The problem I'm facing is related to upgrading my application from sencha touch 2.0.0 to sencha touch 2.3.1. The list that was visible in earlier version is now not visible after upgrade. I have created the fiddle to demonstrate that; displaying 2 lists of items, one using list and other using dataview.
[Check out my fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/2ta)

Run Fiddle with Framework Sencha Touch 2.0.1.1: Both list and dataview are visible with height adjusted to show the items in store.
Run Fiddle with Framework Sencha Touch 2.3.1: List is not visible while dataview is visible with height adjusted to show the items in store.

My question is whether I'm missing anything from config options for list that is required in latest sencha touch version, or I'm left with no other option but to switch to using dataview instead of list.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difference between Touch 2.0.0 and 2.3.1 in List

Config options

scrollable is public in 2.0.0, but private in 2.3.1.

And you can not change the default value. and the value is true always.

you have to override the whole List to get the effect you want to.

or there is another easy way to override the css

```
<style>
.x-list .x-container .x-scroll-container{position:relative;}
.x-list .x-container .x-scroll-container .x-scroll-scroller{position:relative;}
</style>
```